# javascript, fabric.js: How to draw a lines in a cycle "for"?

Tags: javascript

It drawing only one line. I want to draw a grid.

---

```js
var cnvs = new fabric.Canvas('field1');
cnvs.selection = false; 
cnvs.backgroundColor = 'white';
var lin = new fabric.Line([22,23,668,23],{
    strokeWidth: 5,                           
    stroke: 'rgba(100,200,200,0.5)',          
    fill: 'black',                            
    selectable: false,
    hoverCursor: 'default'
});                                       
cnvs.renderOnAddRemove = false;           
for (var y=23;y<500;y=y+50)               
{                                         
    lin.set({x1:22,y1:y,x2:668,y2:y});
    cnvs.Add(lin);
};
```

Thanks._________________________________

Answer (score 0):

```js
function genlin(x1,y1,x2,y2)                   
{                                              
        var lin = new fabric.Line([x1,y1,x2,y2],{
        strokeWidth: 5,                             
 stroke: 'rgba(100,200,200,0.5)',            
 fill: 'black',                              
 selectable: false,   
 hoverCursor: 'default' 
 });                                         
 cnvs.add(lin);                              
};                                             
for (var y=23;y<500;y=y+50) genlin(22,y,668,y);
for (var x=20;x<700;x=x+50) genlin(x,21,x,475);
```